# Instanciar objetos de clase persona en una lista

Tags: c#, lista

Trato de instanciar varios objetos de la clase `Persona`, la cual tiene tres atributos, ¿Cual debe de ser la sintaxis correcta para poder instanciarlo directamente en el constructor de la lista de personas?

```
   // clase persona
   public class persona
   {
         public string Nombre{ get; set; }
         public string Apellidos{ get; set; }
         public int Edad { get; set; }
   }

   // lista
   List<persona> lista = new List<persona>();
```

Me gustaría poder crearlas dentro del propio constructor aunque he probado con el metodo `Add()` y tampoco he sabido hacerlo, ¿Como le dices al metodo Add() que atributo quieres escribir?

Supongo que sera una duda de novato total, pero llevo un rato intentándolo y no lo he conseguido hacer correctamente.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta agregando los intentos que has realizado :D

Comment: Lo mas recomendado es crear el objeto persona y luego agregarlo a la lista con el lista.add(persona);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1- Inicializando los objetos en la inicializacion de la lista:

A esto se llama [Inicializador de colecciones](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers), donde en la inicializacion puedes definir los elementos por defecto sin utilizar el metodo `Add(T)` directamente:

```
 List<Personas> personas = new List<Personas>{
       new Personas { Nombre = "Einer", Apellido = "Einer", Edad = 17 },
       new Personas { Nombre = "Einer", Apellido = "Einer", Edad = 23 },
       new Personas { Nombre = "Einer", Apellido = "Einer", Edad = 28 }
    };

    Console.WriteLine(personas.Count);// 3
```

2 - Inicializando la clase en el metodo `.Add(T)` de la lista:

Y esto es Inicializador de objectos donde se inicializa los datos del objeto en la inicializacion(que es lo mismo que ocurre en el primer ejemplo);

```
var personas = new List<Personas();
personas.Add(new Personas{ Nombre = "Einer" , Apellido = "Einer", Edad = 25 });
```

Comment: Es precisamente lo que buscaba. Gracias a ti y a los demás por la ayuda.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes partir creando el objeto asignando directamente sus variables.

```
var obj = new persona(){
Nombre = "Edulon",
Apellidos = "Martinez Rivera",
Edad = 20
}
```

Y para cargarlos en el ultimo lugar de la lista es sería con

```
lista.add(obj);
```

**Protip** Entiendiedo estos conceptos puedes agregar directamente un objeto a la lista escribiendo en cada atributo a la vez.

```
lista.add(new persona(){
    Nombre = "Edulon",
    Apellidos = "Martinez Rivera",
    Edad = 20
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Las respuestas agregadas anteriormente son correctas, y utilizan la sintaxis moderna de creacion de objetos.

Dejo esta como aclaracion.

Antes, para agregar una objeto a la lista, debias previamente crear el objeto que querias, llenar sus propiedades, y luego agregarlo a la lista.

El codigo que va a terminar produciendo el compilador es el mismo, pero la forma de hacerlo es mas explicita.

Se hacia de la siguiente forma (y mas alla del warning del compilador moderno, anda sin problemas).

```
List<persona> lista = new List<persona>();
persona personanueva = new persona();
personanueva.Nombre = "Gonzalo";
personanueva.Apellido = "B";
personanueva.Edad = "20";
lista.add(personanueva);
```

Esta aclaracion es para usuarios novatos, para que entiendan como funciona internamente lo que muestran las otras respuestas.